# HIVE - create table with complex data type

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

If all collection items are terminated by the same value, then we can use collection terminated by '$' or any character. But my scenario, array type items are terminated by '$' , map items are terminated by '%' and struct items are terminated by '^'. in that case , how can i use collection item terminated by . share your valuable ideas.

Comment: I suggest using Spark to parse your file programmatically

Comment: i am new to hadoop -hive eco system. is there a way to do in hive?

Comment: Fun fact - Spark writes to Hive tables. Hive doesn't really "parse" data, it only queries it.